# Blazor Azure Static Web App not executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor, azure-static-web-app

I'm using a little bit of Javascript in my Blazor app to do some light work. Everything works fine on my local computer. When I publish to my Azure Static Web App, the Javascript does not execute. Here is the error message.

Refused to execute script from 'https://fullUrl/js.download' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my yaml file.

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  # vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true

  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/'
      api_location: ''
      output_location: 'wwwroot'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

I placed this in my staticwebapp.config.json file.

```
"mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json",
    ".js": "application/octet-stream"
  }
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got all of this to work. I renamed myfile.js.download to just myfile.js. I then changed another js file to js.js. Anyway, that seemed to be the change that was needed.

Here is the updated yaml file.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  # vmImage: windows-latest

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'
    projects: 'YourProjectName.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration Release'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    skip_app_build: true
    app_location: '/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/wwwroot'
    output_location: ''
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'YOURDEPLOYMENTTOKEN'
```